# Error creating Heatmap in R: x must be numeric

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to create a simple heatmap on R.
My dataframe looks like following:

```
                % changes@site_1   % changes@site_2
observation_1     0.358249346         2.799098208  
observation_2     0.364915472         2.708782649
observation_3     0.278763325         3.346167761
observation_4     0.16328117          6.540884852
observation_5     0.81721982          1.18541967
observation_6     0.882339386         1.164870413
observation_7     0.70736946          1.359606195
observation_8     0.963131146         1.035026205
observation_9     0.015797898         9.86748686
observation_10    0.215082099         3.458365581
observation_11    0.903703133         1.080001078
observation_12    0.870374479         1.11292402
observation_13    1.163808464         0.912561512
observation_14    1.033157819         0.962176714
```

I made sure to convert the loaded df as a matrix:

```
df <- as.matrix(df)
```

Then, typed heatmap syntax:

```
heatmap(df)
```

However, I got an error as follows:

```
Error in heatmap(df) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

My best guess for the error is that the first column contains strings and numbers.
What would be the best way to resolve this error?
Thank you.

---

*tl;dr* I tried creating a heatmap and converted to matrix, then expected R to create a heatmap, but resulted in an error(stated above). Was not able to find a clear answer while searching previous asked questions on this forum.

Edit 1:

The output of 'dput':

```
dput(df):

structure(c("observation_1", "observation_2", "observation_3", 
"observation_4", "observation_5", "observation_6", "observation_7", 
"observation_8", "observation_9", "observation_10", "observation_11", 
"observation_12", "observation_13", "observation_14", "0.3582493", 
"0.3649155", "0.2787633", "0.1632812", "0.8172198", "0.8823394", 
"0.7073695", "0.9631311", "0.0157979", "0.2150821", "0.9037031", 
"0.8703745", "1.1638085", "1.0331578", "2.7990972", "2.7087826", 
"3.3461678", "6.5408849", "1.1854820", "1.1648704", "1.3596062", 
"1.0350262", "9.8674869", "3.4583656", "1.0800011", "1.1129240", 
"0.9125615", "0.9621767"), dim = c(14L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("X", "X..changes.site_1", "X..changes.site_2")))
```

Output of 'is.numeric(df[,1])':

```
is.numeric(df[,1]):

Error in df[,1]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Edit 2: Removed unnecessary tags

Comment: Did you try not including the column with strings?

Comment: If I read your table in as a data frame, your code works. Can you perhaps include the output from `dput(df)` in your question?

Comment: In addition to Allan’s comment suggesting sharing `dput`, why did you tag the packages `pheatmap`, `complexheatmap`, and `heatmaply`? You don’t seem to use those packages in your code. If you’re not actually looking for solutions with this packages, it is best not to spam with these tags.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but it looks like your "numeric" data is left-justified, which indicates that it is character, not numeric. Just because you use `as.matrix()`, doesn't mean that it converts it to a numeric matrix. What happens if you do `is.numeric(df[,1])`?